# How do you cut and paste a file from one directory to another directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

How do I cut and paste one file from one directory to another directory? I want to do this task using the Command Prompt.

I know I can do this by using the GUI, but I am curious about if I can do this using batch scripting since I am trying to learn it.

Comment: windows or linux or something else? linux you would use cp (copy) mv (move which acts like cut and paste). Windows I think you use the word copy to copy, don't know cut off the top of my head, maybe cut :)

Comment: @Green Day: copy command is working for copy-paste.Thanks..Exactly what I was looking for..

Comment: even more like gui apps: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30825/copy-and-paste-a-file-directory-from-command-line

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`mv` in unix-ish systems, `move` in dos/windows.

e.g.

```
C:\> move c:\users\you\somefile.txt   c:\temp\newlocation.txt
```

and

```
$ mv /home/you/somefile.txt /tmp/newlocation.txt
```

Comment: Can you please suggest me any link from where I can learn Basic Command Prompt Operation.

Comment: What operating system? No point in learning bash on linux if you're on cmd.exe in windows. Googling for tutorials is probably easiest. they'll all have some examples you can learn from.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I am using windows OS only. ya I am searching on Google only but their is vast material I am little confused which has to used. I just want to learn basic command prompt operation and how to create bat file.

Comment: Probably waayyy too old for you but here is a must have link for all things command line on most OSs just go to https://ss64.com/

Answer (score 1):

use the `xclip` which is command line interface to X selections

### install

```
apt-get install xclip
```

### usage

```
echo "test xclip " > /tmp/test.xclip
xclip -i < /tmp/test.xclip
xclip -o > /tmp/test.xclip.out

cat /tmp/test.xclip.out   # "test xclip"
```

enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

E:>move "blogger code.txt" d:/"blogger code.txt"

```
    1 file(s) moved.
```

"blogger code.txt"  is a file name

The file move from E: drive  to D: drive